# Are there any dangers or drawbacks with running PHP inside Java/JSP engine (i.e PHP-Java bridge) such as Tomcat?

Tags: java, php, jsp, zend-framework, php-java-bridge

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2

Web Server: IIS 7.5

JSP Engine: Tomcat 5.5

PHP Engine: PHP 5.3

Note: IIS and JSP communicate using the Apache Tomcat Connector 1.5

Are there any dangers or drawbacks with running PHP inside a Java/JSP engine?  At best, I would like to share a session between JSP and PHP.  At worst, I need to figure out a way to setup session management within PHP, despite the application I'm working with indirectly depends on JSP and PHP.  Recoding the PHP code into JSP is not an option, however.  I'm considering using a bridge or running PHP inside Tomcat but I'm concerned about security.

Is bridging PHP and Java or running PHP inside Tomcat a safe option?

What's important to understand is IIS and Tomcat are connected via the Apache Tomcat Connector.  So, adding PHP into the fold might only increase complexity and I'm not quite sure I can maintain the current setup and add a PHP-JSP bridge, as well.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: For what its worth... I don't have any 'hard evidence' to tell you  - but my experience has been that java bridges have been a pain.  That is to say, you can't say they 'failed' but its always been just like a thorn in my side.  Most often, I try to refactor into using web services to communicate between both layers.  I know that may not be optimal... so, as far as _I_ am aware, there is no 'known' problem with what you are proposing, just my own experience has been that its always seemed a bit 'off.'  Heh -probably not THAT helpful, I know... :(